# Accessing file in windows8 App using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, asynchronous

This is basically for windows 8 app and I'm writing a file using this method -

```
static async void WriteDataCords(int numDataCodewords)
  {
      StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

      var storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("DataCodeWords.txt");
      string data = numDataCodewords.ToString();
      await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, data);
  }
```

and now I'm reading file using this method -

```
        StorageFolder storageFolder7 = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
        var storageFile7 = await storageFolder6.GetFileAsync("DataCodeWords.txt");
        string text7 = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile7);
```

but when I run this program it's throwing an error "Access denied or We can't access the file". Using this approach I'm writing many files and reading.Please let me know how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

My problem is when I'm accessing file to read and display at that time file is involve in writing process so thats why I'm unable to access that file and it's showing an error.
So. Is there any approach by which we only move forward when the  file writing process is complete and than reading process will start?

Comment: Perhaps you should change signature of WriteDataCords to `static async Task ... ` and then have the caller of it await it?

Comment: @Christian - I tried but it's not solving my problem.thanks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SemaphoreSlim` which limits the number of threads that can access a resource.
Below is an example of a class that handles writing/reading for a file. You create an instance of it when you want to write a file and call the WriteDataCords method. Then you need some way to access the correct instance when you want to read and then call ReadDataCords:

```
public class FileReadWrite
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public FileReadWrite(string fileName)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public async Task WriteDataCords(int numDataCodewords)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            var storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            string data = numDataCodewords.ToString();
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, data);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task ReadDataCords()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder6 = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            var storageFile7 = await storageFolder6.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            string text7 = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile7);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

And calling code:

```
public class ClientCode
{
    public async void WriteFile()
    {
        var fileReadWrite = new FileReadWrite("DataCodeWords.txt");
        await fileReadWrite.WriteDataCords(42);
    }

    public async void ReadFile()
    {
        var fileReadWrite = GetFileReadWriteForFile("DataCodeWords.txt"); //Method for retreiving correct instance of FileWriteRead class
        await fileReadWrite.ReadDataCords();
    }

    private FileReadWrite GetFileReadWriteForFile(string fileName)
    {

    }
}
```

You could skip the FileWriteRead class (it adds complexity) and use SemaphoreSlim directly in the original code for writing/reading but then you could only write/read one file at a time (which might not be a problem).